# c# add new item to existing string[,] Array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to use a multidimentional string array.
I can easily create it:

```
string[,] array = new string[,]
{
 {"AA", "AB"},
 {"AC", "AD"},
};
```

no issue here.

The idea is to add some more items after.
The assumption is that my array can be extended for many "rows" but just two "columns".

I've tried to do this:

```
array[0,0] = "AE";
array[0,1] = "AF";
```

but this does not seem to work. Why?

Also is there any way to add (concatenate/join?) e.g. in one go:

```
new string[,] { {"AE", "AF"} }
```

or

```
array[i,???] = {"AE", "AF"}
```

where i can be variable (e.g. to the last position) and the columns wouldn't have to be defined (based on 2 columns defined in the array)

this could add the new item into the existing array (at 3rd position)?

The string[,] is a very good solution to set up your items manually, but if you have external data that requires to be added to the array, I couldn't find any example it on any other posts.

Can someone help?
Thanks.

Regards,

Comment: Arrays are fixed size. You want to use a data structure that isn't fixed size (such as a `List<T>`)

Comment: why don't you use a  List<T> and add new items to your array? for example `array = new List<string>(array) { "AE", "AF" }.ToArray();`

Comment: *The assumption is that my array can be extended for many "rows" but just two "columns".* Why are you assuming this?

Comment: At moment I have a few problems. I've started to use the { { } } structure and it is very easy (manually) to add items. Changing to list would create me a potential problem to have to go back and change it to list. And using List means that I have to use List.Add to each item which makes it more difficult to write (and read).

Comment: I want my array to have as many rows I need, but keep the same number of columns (just 2 like my example)

Answer (score 0):

you need a datastructure that can grow ( and shrink )

try :-

```
var array = new List<string[]> {new[] {"AE", "AF"}, new []{"A", "B"}};
```

and then

```
array.Add(new []{"XY", "AB"});
```

and you can access it like :-

```
Console.WriteLine(array[0][0]);
array[0][0] = "BB";
Console.WriteLine(array[0][0]);
```

If you like array initialization syntax, you can do that first and convert it to a list like :-

```
var initial = new[,] {{"H", "I"}, {"R", "V"}};

var array = Enumerable.Range(0, initial.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)
    .Select(n => new[] {initial[n, 0], initial[n, 1]}).ToList();
```

Comment: Graphically the use of _{ {"A", "B"}, {"C","D"} }_ instead of _array.Add(new[]{"A", "B"} +  array.Add(new[]{"C", "D"} +_ ... imagine 30 lines or more. The first option is always better on that focus. But because I need to extend this option and use it now beyond the manually set number of items (array length), I cannot find a way forward (due to my knowledge limitation). Is this even possible?

Comment: if you look at my code, you don't have to add each one, but you have to have new[].

Comment: updated to show you how to use an array to seed a list

Comment: If I can understand correctly, your suggestion is to use List at the end anyway (which means I might have to change my approach from string[,] to List<string[]>), but allow me to still use my array manually (when needed) and allow me to convert it to list at the end?

Comment: I could use some tips on how you are selecting the individual strings withing the array (I presume .Select(n => new[] {initial[n, 0], initial[n, 1]}).ToList();) and how many rows (from 0 to last row? Enumerable.Range(0, initial.GetUpperBound(0) + 1) ? why the + 1 on "GetUpperBound(0) + 1"?

Comment: you need to have a look at Linq, it's very very very useful,  the upperbound is a index, so if you have 1 item the upperbound is 0,  so for a count, I need to add one

Comment: Thank you very much, Keith.